# Retrieving another entity from a form in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a form which populates a `Project` Doctrine entity in Symfony2.

Let's say the fields are:

```
Name: ______________
Customer: ____________
```

Where `Customer` is another Doctrine entity.

My problem is, I can't manage to retrieve the Customer entity. I tried to retrieve it based on the ID for instance (the field becomes Customer ID) and then, in a prePersist event listener, to set `$project->customer` with the retrieved entity, but it seems overkill to me.

All I want to do is the following:

1. Display a listbox with available `Customer` entities as the Customer field (in `Project` form)
2. In the database, fill the customerId field (in Project table) with the chosen Customer's ID

I'm aware it must be pretty simple, and I'd take 3 minutes to set this up using just PHP/MySQL and some foreign keys, but I simply don't know the best way to do that with Symfony2/Doctrine (meaning in a way that respects the standards and don't look spaghetti).

So, my questions:

1. What should I declare in `MyBundle\Form\ProjectType->buildForm()` function?
2. How should I retrieve the chosen Customer entity and where should I do this in the directory structure (controller, entity, prePersist event listener...)?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide us how your Project<->Customer relationship is defined in your Project class ?

Comment: Just answered your comment by answering my own question. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure your relationship was correctly set, to give you the answer : you have nothing to do ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found an answer. It's really simple :)

**In MyBundle/Form/ProjectType.php:**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name',    'text')
        ->add('customer', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'Me\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity\Customer',
            'property' => 'name'));
}
```

**Then in Project.orm.yml (yeah I like Yaml):**

```
manyToOne:
    customer:
        targetEntity: Customer
        joinColumn:
            name: customerId
            referencedColumnName: id
            nullable: false
```

**Finally, in Customer.orm.yml:**

```
oneToMany:
    projects:
      targetEntity: Project
      mappedBy: customer
```

And that's it! Symfony2 takes care of it all. Just plain magic.